# AJV - Reference external schema without adding it first

Tags: javascript, json, ajv

Is it possible to use AJV to reference a schema that was previously not added through `addSchema()`?

I want to resolve a reference like this:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "$ref": "project-id.schema.json#/definitions/id"
        }
    }
}
```

without explicitly adding `project-id.schema.json` first.

Answer (score 4):

### Given

answer.json

```json
{
  "$id": "stackoverflow://schemas/answer.json",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "$ref": "id.json#"
    }
  }
}
```

id.json

```json
{
  "$id": "stackoverflow://schemas/id.json",
  "type": "string"
}
```

#### Adding all schemas at once via the `schemas` option

```js
const Ajv = require('ajv');
const ajv = new Ajv({
  schemas: [
    require('./id.json'),
    require('./answer.json')
  ]
});

const validate = ajv.getSchema('stackoverflow://schemas/answer.json');

validate(42);
//=> false
validate({id: 42});
//=> false
validate({id: ''});
//=> true
```

#### Loading referenced schemas with the `loadSchema` option

In this case you do need to pass the schema you want to compile as an object but if that schema contains references to other schemas not known by Ajv already, these will be loaded via `loadSchema`:

```js
const Ajv = require('ajv');
const ajv = new Ajv({
  loadSchema: function (uri) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (uri === 'stackoverflow://schemas/id.json') {
        resolve(require('./id.json')); // replace with http request for example
      } else {
        console.log('wat')
        reject(new Error(`could not locate ${uri}`));
      }
    });
  }
});

const test = async () => {
  // Schemas referenced in answer.json will be loaded by the loadSchema function
  const validate = await ajv.compileAsync(require('./answer.json'));
  validate(42) //=> false
  validate({id: 42}) //=> false
  validate({id: ''}) //=> true
}

test();
```